# Discord JS: Extracting data from a collection

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a command where I want to write the `id` of a user in a voice channel into an array. So far, I managed to write the whole collection of the user with `joinedTimestamp` etc. Now I want to extract the `id` of the user from the collection.

My command looks like this:

```
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    let waitingroom = message.guild.channels.cache.get("952324088762867722")
    let player = [];
    let isadmin = message.member.roles.cache.has(adminRole);

    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + 'startgame' && isadmin) {
        player.push(waitingroom.members);
        console.log(player);
    }    
});
```

And this is what I get from the array when 2 users are in the `waitingroom`:

```
[
  Collection(2) [Map] {
    '392776445375545355' => GuildMember {
      guild: [Guild],
      joinedTimestamp: 1646940658665,
      premiumSinceTimestamp: null,
      nickname: null,
      pending: false,
      communicationDisabledUntilTimestamp: null,
      _roles: [Array],
      user: [User],
      avatar: null
    },
    '849388169614196737' => GuildMember {
      guild: [Guild],
      joinedTimestamp: 1647168003344,
      premiumSinceTimestamp: null,
      nickname: 'Test-Account [Nils]',
      pending: false,
      communicationDisabledUntilTimestamp: null,
      _roles: [],
      user: [User],
      avatar: null
    }
  }
]
```

But I only want the user `id`s from the collection. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer is a bit verbose. [`Collection#map()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) returns an array and accepts a callback function, so all you have to do is to iterate over the members and return their `id`s:

```js
let waitingRoom = message.guild.channels.cache.get('952324088762867722')
let memberIDs = waitingRoom.members.map(member => member.id)
```

Now, `memberIDs` is an array of the snowflakes/IDs of the members. No need to create a new array or use the `push` method. Actually, you should never really use `map` with `push` or other methods that mutate arrays.

Answer (score 2):

> Better solution, see accepted answer.

First you need to create a variable with an empty array.
Then you can use the [`.map`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) function of the member [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection) to push the user id's to the array.

```
let arr = [];
<Channel>.members.map(user => {
    arr.push(user.id);
});
```