# DiscordJs How to get Collection Map value

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How do I get the value for author id, content and attachments?

I tried to do msg.content but it returns undefined.

Please help, thank you.

```js
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if(message.channel.id != '123') return;

    message.channel.messages.fetch({limit:1}).then(msg=>{
        console.log(msg);
    })
})
```

The output when I console log msg.

```json
Collection(1) [Map] {
  '1043093898920210513' => <ref *1> Message {
    channelId: '123',
    guildId: '103951360683870',
    id: '1043093898920213',
    createdTimestamp: 1668763365250,
    type: 0,
    system: false,
    content: 'Plank',
    author: User {
      id: '8346389699455442',
      bot: false,
      system: false,
      flags: [UserFlagsBitField],
      username: 'test',
      discriminator: '0001',
      avatar: 'b91b0f76907488b4decbc60baf0c97ad',
      banner: undefined,
      accentColor: undefined
    },
    pinned: false,
    tts: false,
    nonce: '1043093879819075584',
    embeds: [],
    components: [],
    attachments: Collection(1) [Map] { '1043093898634664' => [Attachment] },
    stickers: Collection(0) [Map] {},
  }
}
```

Comment: try `msg.map(m => m.content);`

Comment: The same question has been asked already, please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71456377/2746366).

Comment: What is the expected output? Do you want a new collection, an array, or a single object? To get the first result, you can use `msg.first()`, to get the content, use `msg.first().content`, to get the author ID, use `msg.first().author.id`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the help guys! Both map and first() works.